# How to make a filter in select using the value of another select

Tags: reactjs, select

I'm creating a solution using a select normal  and that a select should contain only the options it does not contain in the other.

I have seen examples with react-select but they don't work for me, do you have any idea how I can do it with a normal selector?

I have this:

```
Constructor: 

    const options = [
        { nombre: "Service 1", value: 1 },
        { nombre: "Service 2", value: 2 },
        { nombre: "Service 3", value: 3 }
    ];


    var arreglo = [];
    Object.keys(options).forEach(function (key) {
        arreglo.push(options[key]);
    });

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value1: false,
            value2: false
            //input.target.value :
        };
    }
```

Onchanges functions of two selectors:

```
onChange = option => {
    if (this.state.value2.value === option.value) {
        this.setState({
            value1: option,
            value2: false
        });

    } else {
        this.setState({ value1: option });
    }
};

onChange2 = option => {
    this.setState({ value2: option });
};


select1:

      <select placeholder="select" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.value1}>
                                        {arreglo.map(p =>
                                            <option key={p.value} value={p.value}>{p.nombre}</option>
                                        )}
                                    </select>

select2:

        <select placeholder="select" defaultValue={this.state.selectValue} onChange={this.onChange2} options= 
     {options.filter(option => option.value !== this.state.value1.value)} value={this.state.value2}>
                                        {arreglo.map(p =>
                                            <option key={p.value} value={p.value}>{p.nombre}</option>
                                        )}
                                        </select>
```

any idea? i try whit this!! please help me!

Thanks

Comment: does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62239420/

Comment: It is not what I want to do. :/