# Dynamically populating dropdown based on 2 JSON files in React

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu

I have 2 JSON files that contain data for regions and provinces respectively.

Here is a sample data for my `regions.json`

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "long_name": "First region in the country",
    "name": "firstRegion",
    "key": "FR"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "long_name": "Second region in the country",
    "name": "secondRegion",
    "key": "SR"
  }
]
```

And this is my `provinces.json`

```
[
  { "id": 1, "name": "province One", "region_key": "FR", "key": "p1" },
  { "id": 2, "name": "province Two", "region_key": "SR", "key": "p2" },
  { "id": 3, "name": "province Three", "region_key": "FR", "key": "p3" },
  { "id": 4, "name": "province Four", "region_key": "SR", "key": "p4" }
]
```

What I want to happen is when the user chooses a region from the first dropdown, for example, `First region in the country`, the second dropdown, which is the provinces dropdown, must be dynamically populated with the provinces that belong to `First region in the country` or provinces with the region_key `FR`. From this logic, I assume there must be some mapping that could happen. I referred to one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62239420/steps-to-populate-dynamic-dropdown-using-arrays-in-reactjs-using-react-hooks) but unfortunately, when I try to edit the `options` value from the provinces' selectcomponent, I get an error `props.options.map is not a function`. Also, my JSON files, I assume, need a different style for mapping? Since I need to match the `key` from `regions.json` to `region.key` in `provinces.json` but I'm fairly new to rendering data from the database to the front-end using React.

Here is a code snippet for my dropdown:

```
/* Dropdown for Regions */
<h4 className="mb-3 text-sm">Regions</h4>
   <Select
     className="basic-multi-select text-sm"
     classNamePrefix="select"
     defaultValue={selectedRegions}
     getOptionLabel={(region) => region.long_name}
     getOptionValue={(region) => region.id}
     isMulti
     name="regions"
     options={regions}
     onChange={handleChangeRegion}
     placeholder="Region select"
     />
/* Dropdown for Provinces */
 <h4 className="mb-3 text-sm">Provinces</h4>
   <Select
     className="basic-multi-select text-sm"
     classNamePrefix="select"
     defaultValue={selectedProvinces}
     getOptionLabel={(province) => province.name}
     getOptionValue={(province) => province.id}
     isMulti
     name="provinces"
     options={provinces}
     onChange={handleChangeProvince}
     placeholder="Province Select"
     />
```

This is my `handleChangeRegion`, for context.

```
const handleChangeRegion = (selectedRegions) => {
    setSelectedRegions([...selectedRegions])
    regionID = []
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(selectedRegions).length; i++) {
      regionID[i] = selectedRegions[i].id
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us which Framework you're using for the "Select" Component or the implementation if you've written it yourself? Also can you provide the code of the handleChangeRegion function?

Comment: @Lavariet I'm using Popovers from headlessui. Also, I've edited my code and added the function for handleChangeRegion. For context, the id for the selection regions are placed in an array in a global var (for the mean time); which explains the emptying of the regionID array for every execution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would go about this:

1. use a `useState` hook for each selection to store the selected value (say `active_region` and `active_province`)
2. use `region.key` as value for the first dropdown
3. filter the `provinces` list based on the selected `region_key` and use this for the second dropdown:

```js
provinces.filter(o => o.region_key === active_region)
```

This is, of course, assuming that you are using functional components (hence my mentioning of hooks)